# Почему в Jenkins показывает что всё собралось, а образ и контейнера в Docker нет? Помогите, кто чем может!

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

В Jenkins прописал команды для Docker, в Jenkins все типа собралось, а образ и контейнер не появился.

```
!/bin/sh
cd /home/jenkins/own-node-image
touch Dockerfile
cat > Dockerfile <<stop
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /home
ADD my-indexjs my-indexjs
RUN echo 1
RUN npm update
RUN echo 2
stop
docker rmi tatasu/own-node-image:v3.0
docker build --build-arg http_proxy=http://10.15.6.142:3128 -t myfolder/own-node-image:v3.0 .
```

Если заменить директорию own-node-image на my-indexjs,  то Не собирается.
А если еще и изменить путь в ADD . geometry-utils, то собирается, но пишет статус "Unused" в Portainer.

Помогите, кто чем может!

Comment: Покажите ваш dockerfile или как вы собираете образ

Comment: @instahipsta282 переформулировал вопрос.